# Why PowerBuilder function Integer("") returns zero

Tags: function, integer, powerbuilder

In PowerBuilder the function Integer("") returns zero. How could it be possible that empty string becomes zero? Why function Integer("") does not return null?

Comment: Since none of us are likely the developer that designed or implemented this function almost 30 years ago, your asking an opinion. However, you’ll be well served keeping this pattern in mind: the only time a simple function returns a null is when the parameter passed is a null. You’ll find it applies often in PowerScript.

Comment: right, :) i liked that enough to smile for a moment "You’ll find it applies often in PowerScript".

Answer (score 1):

This is how the method is defined and has been from its inception.  Invalid input or an incompatible datatype results in a return of zero (0).  If the input is null it returns null.

If you need to distinguish between a string value of zero and non-numeric input, use the IsNumber method to check it prior to using Integer.

Comment: Yes Sir, i followed that from PB help. i was in a good mood when asked my question. really. :)

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is not the same as NULL. Only if the string argument was NULL would the returning number also be NULL as I recall.

I suppose the empty string is equivalent to PB's initial value, so for numbers it would be 0 (zero).

Comment: 0 (zero) is a valid value whereas "" empty string is not a valid number. for example If a fake currency note have value then why its illegal to print it? Validation is the first thing before conversion.

Comment: because i walked away whistling and singing that is why you lost your job. You showed me your teeth with a smile on your face.  In real life, When i gave you a fake note at he currency exchange window you were supposed to call authorities. Rule: illegal = null so empty string 
 must be strictly equals to null for the type conversion function.

Comment: In PowerBuilder an empty string is not equivalent or equal to Null.

Comment: You don't understand. Actually, Integer() function must return null when there is no valid number in the string parameter it received. In very simple words You don't give me something valid when you don't get something valid. isn't it right?

Comment: In PB when the integer function doesn’t receive a valid number in the string parameter it returns 0 by default.

Comment: It’s the behaviour the developers of PB decided to take. Compare with the Date function, when it doesn’t receive a valid date in the string parameter, it returns the default date 01-01-1900 !

Comment: I guess you know why things went wrong with Sybase. reason is quite simple the Integer() function could say "sorry, i cannot do that" but the damn function said "your Integer is ready".

Comment: That's what i call bad behavior. And my rule is still intact "DON'T GIVE ME SOMETHING OBNOXIOUSLY VALID WHEN YOU GET SOMETHING TERRIBLY VALID". In very simple words , if you cannot do something right then don't give me something wrong. Isn't that right?

Comment: Yeah, I would work around that by pre-checking the string for "emptyness" and acting accordingly: E.g.:

`int i_result  
string s_source, s_original = ""  
  
// assigning to another string to keep the original intact  
s_source = s_original   

if s_source = "" then setnull( s_source )  
  
i_result = integer( s_source )`

Comment: Oh okay, Please check this https://answers.sap.com/questions/300798/toolbar-disappear-when-ole-control-get-focus.html
And this one is more important than the work around with Integer()  you wrote.